# Deluge - Remove the "C:\fakepath"

Tags: javascript, jquery, deluge

I'm trying to remove the **C:\fakepath**.

Here is the JavaScript of the creation and handler of the input:

```
Ext.ns("Deluge.add");
Deluge.add.FileWindow=Ext.extend(Deluge.add.Window, {
    title: _("Add from File"), layout: "fit", width: 350, height: 115, modal: true, plain: true, buttonAlign: "center", closeAction: "hide", bodyStyle: "padding: 10px 5px;", iconCls:"x-deluge-add-file", initComponent:function() {
        Deluge.add.FileWindow.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        this.addButton(_("Add"), this.onAddClick, this);
        this.form=this.add({
            xtype:"form", baseCls:"x-plain", labelWidth:35, autoHeight:true, fileUpload:true, items:[ {
                xtype:"fileuploadfield", id:"torrentFile", width:280, height:24, emptyText:_("Select a torrent"), fieldLabel:_("File"), name:"file", buttonCfg: {
                    text: _("Browse")+"..."
                }
            }]
        });
    }, onAddClick:function(c, b) {
        if(this.form.getForm().isValid()) {
            this.torrentId=this.createTorrentId();
            this.form.getForm().submit( {
                url: deluge.config.base+"upload", waitMsg: _("Uploading your torrent..."), failure: this.onUploadFailure, success: this.onUploadSuccess, scope: this
            }
            );
            var a=this.form.getForm().findField("torrentFile").value;
            a=a.split("\\").slice(-1)[0];
            this.fireEvent("beforeadd", this.torrentId, a)
        }
    }, onGotInfo:function(d, c, a, b) {
        d.filename=b.options.filename;
        this.fireEvent("add", this.torrentId, d)
    }
    , onUploadFailure:function(a, b) {
        this.hide();
        Ext.MessageBox.show( {
            title: _("Error"), msg: _("Failed to upload torrent"), buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK, modal: false, icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR, iconCls: "x-deluge-icon-error"
        }
        );
        this.fireEvent("addfailed", this.torrentId)
    }
    , onUploadSuccess:function(c, b) {
        this.hide();
        if(b.result.success) {
            var a=b.result.files[0];
            this.form.getForm().findField("torrentFile").setValue("");
            deluge.client.web.get_torrent_info(a, {
                success: this.onGotInfo, scope: this, filename: a
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<form class="x-plain-body x-plain-body-noheader x-form" method="POST" id="ext-gen248" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="height: auto; width: 328px;">
   <div class="x-form-item " tabindex="-1" id="ext-gen269">
      <label for="torrentFile" style="width:35px;" class="x-form-item-label">Fichier:</label>
      <div class="x-form-element" id="x-form-el-torrentFile" style="padding-left:40px">
         <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-file-wrap" id="ext-gen270" style="width: 280px; height: 24px;">
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="torrentFile" class="x-form-text x-form-field x-form-file-text" readonly="" style="width: 209px;"><input id="torrentFile-file" name="file" class="x-form-file" type="file" size="1">
            <table id="ext-comp-1386" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn x-form-file-btn x-btn-noicon" style="width: auto;">
               <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
                  <tr>
                     <td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                     <td class="x-btn-tc"></td>
                     <td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                     <td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen271" class=" x-btn-text">Parcourir...</button></em></td>
                     <td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                     <td class="x-btn-bc"></td>
                     <td class="x-btn-br"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I tried to get the event when the input is changed but no success.

What I tried :

```
$('#torrentFile-file').change(function(){
    alert('ok');
})
```

And:

```
$('#torrentFile-file').on('change', function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. Here is how I made it :

```
$(document.body).on('change',"#torrentFile-file",function (e) {        
    var path = $('#torrentFile-file').val();
    var filename = path.replace(/^.*\\/, "");
    $('#torrentFile').val(filename);
});
```